# Es posible cambiarle el nombre a la base de datatos que se usa desde el controlador con laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo actualmente un controlador en donde quiero pasarle el nombre de la base de datos que necesitare hay manera de hacerlo directamente desde un controlador? editar el .env o el config database desde la carpeta config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero deberías configurar tus diferentes conexiones en tu archivo database.php, dentro del array "connections":

```
'connections' => [

    'conexion1' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'SERVER'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '49447'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'NOMBRE_BD_1'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    ],

    
    'conexion2' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'SERVER'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '49447'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'NOMBRE_BD_2'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    ],
```

Luego, digamos que la función dentro de tu controlador recibe un parámetro con el nombre de la conexión, simplemente la referencias al hacer tu query:

```
public function getUsuarios(Request $req){
$nombreconexion = $req->nombreconexion;
$data=DB::connection($nombreconexion)->table('usuarios')->where('categoria', 'empleado')->get();
}
```